# Best way of displaying a Message box or Confirmation box in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, dialog, custom-action

I came across requirement for message box like everyday since around a year now, I tried jQuery plugins, JavaScripts alert but am still not sure which way would be the best way of doing it.

I want to display a message box within ASP.NET Page (well its actually sharepoint application page).

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/_layouts/abc/simple.master"  Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.LayoutsPageBase" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%> 
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>

<script runat="server">

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a= aa(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
        string b= bb(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());

        mm(a, b);

        Uri uu= Request.UrlReferrer;
        if (uu!= null)
            Response.Redirect(uu.ToString());

        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("alert(\"write here what you want\")");
    }
```

Now it doesn't work but it could be some syntax error but what If I want to display a proper message box(e.g. jquery's plugin http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog in a way that it doesn't do refresh to page) what can I do.

what am actually developing is a Custom Action for SharePoint Document Library.

> **EDIT**
>
> Summary of what I already explained is in SharePoint 2007 I
>   have to develop/design or use message box plugins code behind most
>   times (server-side) e.g. in ASP.NET code behind with C#. Now I seen
>   tens of question asking for that but non of them are actually giving a
>   proper explanation in accordance to best practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't raise a MessageBox in the server. You must write the code so the client HTML+JS raise the alert when needed. If you need some confirmation page, you need to build the page and post the results back when the user press YES or NO

Comment: thanks but why I can't raise a MessageBox in the server, I don't need confirmation page, I want a nice message box, but I just realized I am redirecting in Page Load function and then trying to write a response with javascript alert, but I want a jquery plugin anyway, I think I can put redirecting code in messagebox

Comment: Because the code running in the server can't interact with the UI (Just imagine a MessageBox poping up in a server the middle of a DataCenter :)
You only can generate client code.

Comment: ahhh, got it thanks but still confused with what I am trying to do tho :)

Comment: Yes, I understand. It's the first thing that occurred to me when I started web development. What are you trying to do? What message do you want to show to the user?

Comment: I explained a bit more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402297/asp-net-page-cycle-confusion