# ASP.NET Page Cycle Confusion

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, .net-2.0

If I have a button on my ASP.NET page which will take you to another page but that page will do something and then will send user back using

```
 Uri uu= Request.UrlReferrer;
        if (uu!= null)
            Response.Redirect(uu.ToString());
```

Now Which page event can I use so that when other pages displays I can display a message box.

In short I am running my custom code in a "aspx" page where user is directed on button click, and then after custom code I am sending user back to old page, but it happens so quickly that user doesn't realize that he went on another page, now I want to display a message box after redirect on same page user started from, what to do :S !

[More Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401491/best-way-of-displaying-a-message-box-or-confirmation-box-in-asp-net/13402074#13402074)

**EDIT**

> Sorry guys but I can't make changes to ASP page where button is at all
>   :(

Comment: Why can't you just do the logic on the same page, on the postback? Implementing Response.Redirect() like that will cause a ThreadAbortionException, which is bad for performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit unsure about how the `Request.UrlReferrer` gets set. I think it's a browser implementation detail. So I wouldn't trust on that.

I would go for something like

```
A.aspx -> Redirects to -> B.aspx

B.aspx -> Redirects to -> B.aspx?message=1
```

And check if message=1 is set.

But if you want to use  the `Request.UrlReferrer` it should be accessible on `Page_Load`

Answer (score 1):

If you use it this way, it'll never appear to the client. 
Maybe try redirecting back using javascript with a delay so user can be informed

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do it's add a flag to the redirected page so you can show something special when the flag is turned on

```
Uri uu= Request.UrlReferrer;
if (uu!= null)
    Response.Redirect(uu.ToString() + "?Message=DataHasChanged");
```

and then in the ASP page

```
<% if (Request.QueryString["Message"] == "DataHasChanged") { %>
    <div class="alert">The data has changed. Please review it or whatever</div>
<% } %>
```